# Using reflection with generic types and implicit conversions

Tags: c#, reflection, openxml

I'm trying to use reflection to set properties on some OpenXML types (e.g. Justification).  Assigning a value by enumerating all possibilities is straight-forward:

```
// attr is an XmlAttribute, so .Name and .Value are Strings
if (attr.Name == "Val")
{
    if (element is Justification)
    {
        ((Justification)element).Val = (JustificationValues)Enum.Parse(typeof(JustificationValues), attr.Value);
            return;
    }
    else
    {
        // test for dozens of other types, such as TabStop
    }
}
```

What makes this difficult to do via reflection is:
1) The type of the Val property is EnumValue<T>, so I don't know how to extract the type to pass as the first argument to Enum.Parse.
2) There is an implicit conversion from the actual enumeration type to the EnumValue<> type, which I don't know how to invoke with reflection.

I would like the code to end up looking something like:

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = element.GetType().GetProperty(attr.Name);
Object value = ConvertToPropType(pInfo.PropertyType, attr.Value); /* this 
    would return an instance of EnumValue<JustificationValues> in this case */
pInfo.SetValue(element, value, null);
```

How do I implement ConvertToPropType?  Or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Edit:
I got a solution working using Earwicker's suggestion, but it relies on the convenient fact that the enumeration's type name can be derived from the node's type name ("Justification" -> "JustificationValues").  I'm still curious how to solve this in the general case, though.

Edit2:
GetGenericArguments got me the rest of the way there.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the update to my answer? It shows how to get the enum type from the property type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the attribute value is just a string, I assume you already have some way of figuring out that the string identifies a value from a specific enumeration. In your example you have it hard-coded, so I'm not sure if that's what you want or what you want to change.

Assuming you know it's an enumeration, and you know which enumeration, you already know how to get an object containing a boxed value of the right `enum` type, as in your snippet.

Now if I assume `EnumValue<T>` has a constructor that takes a `T`.

```
Type genericType = typeof(EnumValue<>);
Type concreteType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(JustificationValues));
```

Now `concreteType` is the type `EnumValue<JustificationValues>`.

From that you can get a constructor, hopefully one that takes a `JustificationValues` parameter, and `Invoke` it.

**Update**

Ahh, I see what you're doing now. You use the XML attribute name to pick a C# property. You need to be able to detect whether that property is of a type `EnumValue<T>`, and find out what `T` is.

```
PropertyInfo p = // ... get property info

Type t = p.GetType();

if (t.IsGenericType && 
    t.GetGenericTypeDefinition == typeof(EnumValue<>))
{
    Type e = t.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // get first (and only) type arg

    // e is the enum type...
```

Give that a try.

Comment: I don't know the enumeration type in general, it depends on the type of element.  I didn't know about MakeGenericType but I don't think I'll be able to use it until I figure out how to extract the type T from a type EnumValue<T>

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed that you were looking up the property using the attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.0 adds support to do a late bound implict or explict conversion. This is simplified in the open source framework [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) with it's static method called [InvokeConvert](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_InvokeConvert%28object_target,_Type_type,_bool_explict_=fa). In your ideal example it would work like this:

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = element.GetType().GetProperty(attr.Name);
Object value = Impromptu.InvokeConvert(attr.Value, pInfo.PropertyType); 
pInfo.SetValue(element, value, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might only work with basic types but it was good enough for what I'm doing

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = element.GetType().GetProperty(attr.Name);
Object value = System.Convert.ChangeType(attr.Value, pInfo.PropertyType);
pInfo.SetValue(element, value, null);
```